# Caracteres con acentos no se muestran en PyPi

Tags: python, python-3.x, markdown

Por fin despues de tantas preguntas en el sitio logré subir un paquete a **PyPi**, pero ahora el detalle es como se muestra el **README.md**, pueden verlo mejor [aquí](https://pypi.org/project/pipmanager/). Las letras con acentos no se muestran correctamente, las dos lineas referentes a dicho archivo en el archivo setup.py tiene así las siguientes líneas:

```
long_description = long_description,
long_description_content_type = 'text/markdown; charset=UTF-8',
```

¿Tiene algo que ver con la configuracion o debo subir mis archivos en ingles?

Comment: Hace algún tiempo (cuando lanzaron warehouse...) hice algunas pruebas con ello, creo recordar que no había que especificar el charset, en este caso bastaría con `long_description_content_type = "text/markdown"`, especifica el encoding en open para que no se dependiente de la plataforma : `with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:`. A ver si tengo tiempo y hago algunas pruebas en TestPyPI..., pero definitivamente puedes subir la descripción en Español sin problemas, de eso estoy seguro.

Comment: Me ha costado, pero aquí tienes un paquete con la descripción en Español usando MarkDown: https://pypi.org/project/pyelectrica/#description

Comment: @FJSevilla ¡Excelente! Resuelto. Una solución bastante logica pero que no mencionan en los tutoriales. Deberías colocarlo como respuesta. Así stackoverflow me deja de decir que coloque recompensa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyPI siempre ha admitído descripciones en texto plano y reStructuredText (reST) y desde el despliegue de Warehouse se acepta también Markdown (RFC 7763).

La estructura de los valores para el campo `long_description_content_type` es la misma que para el encabezado `Content-Type` en HTTP (`tipo/subtipo`). Además, opcionalmente pude tener otros parámetros opcionales:

```
<tipo>/<subtipo>; charset = <juego de caracteres> [; <nombre_parámetro> = <valor_de_parámetro> ...]
```

Los valores legales para `tipo/subtipo` son solo tres:

- `text/plain`
- `text/x-rst`
- `text/markdown`

El parámetro `charset` solo tiene un único valor legal que es `UTF-8`. Si se omite, se supone que es UTF-8, por lo que no tiene utilidad alguna, más allá de ser explícitos.

Los otros parámetros suelen estar relacionados con el subtipo elegido. En el caso de Markdown:

- `GFM` para Markdown de Github (por defecto).
- `CommonMark` para CommonMark.

Si el valor nos es válido se asume que es `text/plain`. Si no se especifica por defecto es `text/x-rst; charset=UTF-8`.

Por otro lado, aunque no debería ser un problema dada la estandarización de UTF-8 en el mundo web, es recomendable siempre pasar a `open` el encoding correcto del fichero. Por defecto, dicho parámetro es `None`, lo que significa que depende del encoding local del sistema que ejecuta el script, el cual se obtiene mediante una llamada a `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`.

en definitiva, no deberías tener ningún problema para que PyPI renderize el MarkDown y muestre caracteres como las tildes (o cualquier carácter incluido en `UTF-8`) con:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from setuptools import setup

with open("README.md", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    # ...
)
```